# Is it safe to overwrite native javascript function names for custom objects?

Tags: javascript, native-methods

Is it safe, when creating a custom object, to give it methods (in my current case, "read", "write" & "save") that overwrite native js functions?

The object in question will never have to write to the DOM (or otherwise use the function(s) it'd be losing); these method names are just ideal, so I got curious, and then was surprised to have a hard time finding a clear answer to this. Example below. Thanks.

```
/**
 * Ticket class
 * @param category
 * @param issuedBy
 * @param reissuable If true, lock cannot be overridden by the same method that locked it
 * @returns {Ticket}
 * @constructor
 */
Ticket = function (category, issuedBy, reissuable) {
    //properties
    this.id = Date.now().toString();
    this.category = category;
    this.resolved = false;
    this.issuingMethod = issuedBy;
    this.reissuable = reissuable === true;
    this.data = {};

    //methods
    this.resolve = function () { return this.resolved = true;};
    this.read = function (dataPath) { // find dataPath in this.data }
    this.write = function (dataPath, value) { // add value to dataPath of this.data}

    return this;
};
```

Comment: You... aren't overwriting any built-in functions... You're assigning properties to `this`, the instantiated object...

Comment: The short answer is: go ahead, it won't hurt anything. A longer answer is: this is probably bad practice for long term maintainability, but won't actually hurt anything. The correct answer is from @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Right—and I am still very much learning JS—but it was my understanding that certain functions are always inherited by a new Object (and, much more embarrassingly, my IDE is treating these methods as extant, so there was some amount of inference here..).

Comment: @Jonline I am not sure why you changed the selected answer? The other answer brings nothing new and has actually less information than mine... The defensive programming solution presented in the answer is also of very bad taste and should be avoided in favor of using appropriate code quality tools.

Comment: Sorry @plalx; your second comment in the @JuanMendes' answer seemed to suggest that you thought his answer was actually better (also, I was basically doing this business live, last night, and I'm pretty sure your updated answer isn't the one I initially checked; then, when I noticed Juan's point that I wouldn't be penalized for switching, did so without noticing your having updated. Honestly I was just trying to select as the correct answer the one everyone else seemed to favor. Sorry. I'll run through your answers and find a couple that could be (usefully) upvoted to offset my mess. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not completely safe. When your constructor is called without `new`, `this` points to the global object.

```
var ticket = Ticket(); //this.document will point to the global document object
```

They key to understanding your code is that it uses `this` which is a special keyword that can mean different things;

- When not within a function, it means `window` (`<script>alert(this.name)</script>`)
- When called as a standalone function without an object attached to it, (`alert()`), `this` points to the `window` object
- When called with dot syntax `(ticket.resolve())`, `this` points to the object on the left of the dot (`ticket`).
- When called as a constructor (`new Ticket`), `this` is a new empty object that has `Ticket.prototype` in its prototype chain.
- When called from inline HTML handlers(`onclick="alert(this.id)"`), `this` points to the HTML element where you attached the event
- When called from functions like `setTimeout`, `setInterval` and AJAX callbacks, `this` usually points to `window`
- When a function is called using `apply` or `call`, you can specify what `this` will be
- You can usually use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make sure your function is called with the right

In the case for calling `var ticket = Ticket()`, all your code like `this.name = 'something'` would be creating or overwriting existing global variables, in this case, the `name` of the window.

If you care about this problem you can mitigate this problem by doing the following.

```
    Ticket = function (category, issuedBy, reissuable) {
    if (!this instanceof Ticket) { // called as a function
         return new Ticket(category, issusedBy, reissuable);
    }
    //properties
    this.id = Date.now().toString();
```

To do it in a generic way, you can see this link http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html

Note that this would be probably unnecessary boiler plate code and can be avoided by [following code conventions and enforcing them](http://anton.kovalyov.net/p/why-jshint/)

Comment: True, but usually that would not be an issue if you JSHint your code ;)

Comment: @plalx But technically, this is still the right answer. And sadly enough, most people do not JSHint their code ;)

Comment: +1 Yes, that is definitely a possibility, but in this case it will lead to much more issues that only overriding a native member. Honestly I really dislike this type of defensive programming. If you are using the right tools, which you should be doing, then it's not necessary at all, but I agree it's worth mentionning.

Comment: That's a great tip, as always on StackOverflow, it pains one not to be able to hand out correct answers all over the place and , having already checked @JuanMendes, can't afford the -2 for un-checking on my measily karma. But thank you!

Comment: @plalx I also am not a friend of strict defensive programming and don't use it on most of my code. But for a class inheritance library, it would be good to put in.

Comment: @Jonline I feel you, specially since you don't have many privileges until after around 1k or so. I don't think you would lose 2 points though, because you would gain them back by accepting a different answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the provided code sample you aren't overriding any native [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) methods. However, you could potentially override native methods inherited from `Object.prototype` if you aren't careful.

```
function MyObject() {}

MyObject.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function () { return true; };

new MyObject().hasOwnProperty('test'); //true
```

Clearly that would be misleading and in this case I would opt for another function name with a similar meaning in your domain rather than overriding the native `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` function.

It has been said in another answer that calling a constructor without the `new` keyword could also potentially override global native variables. While this is very true, it will have quite more negative repercussions than only potentially overriding a native global variable. **Linting your code (like you should) using great tools such as JSHint will avoid these mistakes.**

Comment: Gorgeous answer. Thanks.

Comment: You could also create globals and overwrite them... adding an answer